# Create a single row from a MYSQL join that has a 1 to many relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two MYSQL tables that I need to join, the first is called orders the other is called orderdetails. The problem is this; each order can have multiple orderdetails. I want to join them in such a way that the output only generates a single row for each order, with its related productcode and productname entries in columns productcode1, productcode2… productcode5 and productname1… productname5 respectively. I’ve seen answers to similar problems like this, that use GROUP_CONCAT to place the entries into a single column but is there a way to place the entries into columns? Thanks

```
orders
+-------------+
|orderid      |
|firstname    |
|secondname   |
|paymentamount|
+-------------+

ordersdetails
+----------------+
| ordersdetailid |
| orderid        |
| productcode    |
| productname    |
+----------------+

Output
+----------------+
| orderid         |
| productcode1    |
| productcode2    |
| productcode3    |
| productcode4    |
| productcode5    |
| productname1    |
| productname2    |
| productname3    |
| productname4    |
| productname5    |
+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

use `union`:

```
select orderid from orders where orderid=?
Union 
select orderid from ordersdetails t1 join orders t2 on t1.orderid=t2.orderid where orderid=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`.

**Query**

```
SET @o_id := 2; -- your order id here

SELECT orderid AS order_details
FROM orders
WHERE orderid = @o_id
UNION ALL
SELECT productcode FROM ordersdetaild
WHERE orderid = @o_id
UNION ALL
SELECT productname FROM ordersdetaild
WHERE orderid = @o_id;
```

For sorting purpose,

```
SET @o_id := 2; -- your order id here

SELECT t.order_details FROM(
  SELECT orderid AS order_details, 1 AS order_by
  FROM orders
  WHERE orderid = @o_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT productcode, 2 AS order_by FROM ordersdetaild
  WHERE orderid = @o_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT productname, 3 AS order_by FROM ordersdetaild
  WHERE orderid = @o_id
)t
ORDER BY t.order_by, t.order_details;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output implies you don't want a single row per product, but your question states that you do. Hence people are answering about using UNION. I don't think that's what you actually mean though.

I think you're actually wanting to do is to output something like:
OrderId, ProductCode1, ProductCode2, ProductName1, ProductName2.

If that is correct, you can construct that from a few queries.
Firstly pivot the OrderDetails table on OrderId, outputting ProductCode.
Then, do the same for ProductName.

Then, you should be able to join the Order table against those two pivoted tables to get a single row for the Order that has all the Order Details in the way that I have interpreted you want them.

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry for not being clear. Any help with constructing your solution?